# I'm trying to copy this code for instagram video scraping for compilations but it's giving me these errors, what can I do to fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm, youtube-api, screen-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su1Xt.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20IXq.jpg)

Hi, im new to python, what could be the issue and what can be done to fix this? Help would be much appreceated.

```
 File "C:\Users\Georgs\PycharmProjects\automated_youtube_channel\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrape_videos import scrapeVideos
  File "C:\Users\Georgs\PycharmProjects\automated_youtube_channel\scrape_videos.py", line 2, in <module>
    import dateutil.relativedelta
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'
```

Comment: `dateutil` isn't a built-in module, you need to install it - perhaps via `pip install python-dateutil`.

Answer (score 0):

Install dateutil with pip:

`pip install python-dateutil`